# bottomest element on screen and scrolldown position: ff vs chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a quite big height. The height is superior to the window's height, so the scrolldown is displayed on the right of the screen:

[image]

The bottom border of the div matches perfectly the bottom of the displayed area:

[image]

I need to display a bit more than that though because I allow users to resize this div, and they need some space to hover the bottom border.

What I do, is add a 5px bottom margin and it works in Chrome:

[image]

But Firefox or IE11 don't react to that at all.

What can I do?

Random code to illustrate:

No space in the bottom:

```
<div style="position: absolute; border: 1px dotted silver; width: 20px; height: 2000px; margin-bottom: 0px"><div>
```

Space in the bottom only for chrome:

```
<div style="position: absolute; border: 1px dotted silver; width: 20px; height: 2000px; margin-bottom: 5px"><div>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ynjuwqez/1/

Comment: What you can do is show some actual code.

Comment: It's a behavioral problem. I don't have code to show because it's a complex 90k code lines application. Just draw a `<div></div>` with a height of 2000px, and add a margin-bottom.

Comment: I would have to agree with @Nit. I already tried adding a large `div` (as you suggest) and see the correct results in IE11, chrome, and firefox. Is the element floating possibly?

Comment: Ok, see fiddle then. In firefox, if you scroll at the bottomest, there's no 5px space.

Comment: That's what I suspected. The `position: absolute` is the culprit. Now to come up with a solution

Comment: Can you change your `position` to `relative`?

Comment: @bbennett crap, no I can't, it screws up the whole inner layout unfortunately. But it's still a valid answer... (though I don't get why it makes a difference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a pseudo-element of same height, but a bit shifted down:

```css
div:after {
  content: '';        /* enable the pseudo-element */
  position: absolute; /* absolutely positioned (relatively to target) */
  height: 100%;       /* as tall as the target */
  width: 1px;         /* some width */
  margin-top: 5px;    /* this will produce some space at the bottom */
  z-index: -1;        /* hide it behind the background */
}
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px dotted silver;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2000px;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: As per basic post timing comparison, I accept your answer rather than bbennett's. Thanks a lot for your help, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, when you absolutely position an element, it is taken out of the structure of the DOM. This would mean the other elements that need to "space" themselves wouldn't be aware of its existence.

With that being said, I couldn't find any explanation of how/why chrome actually does render the margin.

In any case, you can use the `:after` pseudo class to add a margin to the end.

```
.myDiv:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    bottom: -5px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
}
```

You would also need to remove the `margin-bottom` from your actual div because it would add double margin in chrome. The `width: 1px;` is needed for Firefox to render the `:after` element.